# merge sort not giving correct output, c

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

i have made a merge sort code using pointers since i would like to make the code dynamic once it works and its giving the wrong output.Could it be done using dynamic global arrays,if so how?and what is wrong with the following code:

```
    #include<stdio.h>
void merge(int *a,int low,int mid,int high,int n){
    int l1=low,l2=mid+1,i;
    int b[n];

    for(i=low;l1<=mid&&l2<=high;i++){
        if((*(a+(l1 )))<(*(a+(l2 )))){
            b[i]=*(a+(l1 ));
            l1++;
        }
        else{
            b[i]=*(a+(l2 ));
            l2++;

        }
    }
    while(l1<=mid){
        b[i++]=(*(a+(l1 )));
        l1++;
    }
  while(l2<=mid){
        b[i++]=(*(a+(l1 )));
        l2++;
    }
    for(i=low;i<=high;i++){
       ( *(a+(l1 )))=b[i];
    }
}
void sort(int *a,int low,int high,int n){
    if(low<high){
        int mid=(low+high)/2;
        sort(a,low,mid,n);
        sort(a,mid+1,high,n);
        merge(a,low,mid,high,n);

    }
    else {
        return;

    }
}
int main(void){
        int a[3]={5,2,1};

    sort(&a[0],0,2,3);
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        printf("%d ",a[i]);
    }
}
```

or if anyone has any ideas to make this program using a dynamic sized array i am fine with that.I also made a code for this without pointers which works but uses global variables and hence fixed arrays.I am posting it below just for reference as all I did was implement pointers in that code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int a[6]={5,2,1,6,3,4};
int b[6];
void merge(int low,int mid,int high){
    int l1=low,l2=mid+1,i;
    for(i=low;l1<=mid&&l2<=high;i++){
        if(a[l1]<a[l2]){
            b[i]=a[l1++];
        }
        else{
            b[i]=a[l2++];

        }
    }
    while(l1<=mid){
        b[i++]=a[l1++];
    }
  while(l2<=mid){
        b[i++]=a[l2++];
    }
    for(i=low;i<=high;i++){
        a[i]=b[i];
    }
}
void sort(int low,int high){
    if(low<high){
        int mid=(low+high)/2;
        sort(low,mid);
        sort(mid+1,high);
        merge(low,mid,high);

    }
    else {
        return;

    }
}
int main(void){
    sort(0,5);
    for(int i=0;i<=6;i++){
        printf("%d ",a[i]);
    }
}
```

after changing the code to the following to debug better:I founnd that b is not being assigned the value and nor is a :

```
    #include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void merge(int *a,int low,int mid,int high,int n){
    int l1=low,l2=mid+1,i;
    int *b=malloc(n );

    for(i=low;l1<=mid&&l2<=high;i++){
        if((*(a+(l1 )))<(*(a+(l2 )))){
            (*(b+(i )))=*(a+(l1 ));
        debug  pritnf("%d\n",(*(b+(i ))));
            l1++;
        }
        else{
            (*(b+(i )))=*(a+(l2 ));

            l2++;

        }
    }
    while(l1<=mid){
        (*(b+(i )))=(*(a+(l1 )));
        l1++;
        i++;
    }
  while(l2<=mid){
        (*(b+(i )))=(*(a+(l1 )));
        l2++;
        i++;
    }
    for(i=low;i<=high;i++){
       ( *(a+(l1 )))=(*(b+(i )));
    }
}
void sort(int *a,int low,int high,int n){
    if(low<high){
        int mid=(low+high)/2;
        sort(a,low,mid,n);
        sort(a,mid+1,high,n);
        merge(a,low,mid,high,n);

    }
    else {
        return;

    }
}
int main(void){
        int a[3]={5,2,1};

    sort(&a[0],0,2,3);
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        printf("%d ",a[i]);
    }
}
```

After this started working and it works completely i tried dynamic array and it is not providing me with the right output as in theere are zeroes int he middle and the biggest number(s) are not there.The code is as follows:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void merge(int *a,int low,int mid,int high,int n){
    int l1=low,l2=mid+1,i;
    int *b=malloc((n-1) *sizeof(int));

    for(i=low;l1<=mid&&l2<=high;i++){
        if((*(a+(l1 )))<=(*(a+(l2 )))){
            (*(b+(i )))=*(a+(l1 ));
            l1++;
        }
        else{
            (*(b+(i )))=*(a+(l2 ));

            l2++;

        }
    }
    while(l1<=mid){
        (*(b+(i )))=(*(a+(l1 )));
        l1++;
        i++;
    }
  while(l2<=mid){
        (*(b+(i )))=(*(a+(l1 )));
        l2++;
        i++;
    }
    for(i=low;i<=high;i++){
       ( *(a+(i )))=(*(b+(i )));
    }
}
void sort(int *a,int low,int high,int n){
    if(low<high){
        int mid=(low+high)/2;
        sort(a,low,mid,n);
        sort(a,mid+1,high,n);
        merge(a,low,mid,high,n);

    }
    else {
        return;

    }
}
int main(void){
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
        int a[n];


    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("%d ",a[i]);
    }

    sort(&a[0],0,n-1,n);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("%d ",a[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: 'what is wrong with the following code' - you didn't debug it?

Comment: I did but i am unable to determine that

Comment: Why not?  What happens if you just pass 2 values and step through with your debugger?

Comment: well it still is very confusing

Comment: although i have determined it down to this the pointer location are not working like indexes

Comment: not thats not it

Comment: Try debugging you program with a good debugger, After having a look at your program you increment the a pointer with the `sizeof(int)` in this kind of situation `(a+(i*sizeof(int)))` if you increase a pointer by one it automatically increment by the size of four. you can try by replacing it with `(a+i)`. Hope this helps.

Comment: the pointer is working fine and no matter how good of a debugger i try since it is in recursion it does not help

Comment: you might also want to check your indices again. E.g. you always work with the offset from 0 in a, except when calling sort recursively, and you don't increment i in the two while-loops in merge

Comment: also, you never do a comparison on the value of `a` at position `mid`, as your condition in the for loop has `l1<mid` and starts with `l2=mid+1`. So neither `l1` nor `l2` ever take the value mid. The condition should be `l1<= mid` (at two places).

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Comment: 1) `low*sizeof(int)` : It is a mistake to multiply the index by `sizeof(int)`. In pointer arithmetic it is not necessary to multiply such object sizes. 2) `i<=6` --> `i<6`

Comment: 'the pointer is working fine and no matter how good of a debugger i try since it is in recursion it does not help' which is why, two hours ago, before all the thrashing about with 'it doesn't work' and guesswork, I asked 'What happens if you just pass 2 values and step through with your debugger?'.  That question was not for fun.  It was a suggestion to restrict the recursion and make debug easier.  As afer as I can see, you have done no debugging at all, merely issued code and some guesses to try an elicit a complete debug and test from other SO users:((

Comment: If, as you suggest, you have an IDE, you have no excuse for not using the integrated debugger to follow one or two levels of recursion, making notes of var values while stepping through, and so identifying bugs and fixing them, (apart from "it's hard, boring work").

Comment: @ThingyWotsit I did not see the comment with two values I will certainly try and get back to you

Comment: after trying i still cannot figure out as it works witth an array of size 2 and my point is that the I only implemented pointers in a working version of the code that uses global variable which i posted above

Comment: @BLUEPIXY what do you suggest then instead of multiplying by sizeof(int)

Comment: E.g `int a[]={ 1,2,3 }, *p;` , `p = &a[1];`. now pointer `p` point to `a[1]`(`2`) ,  `p = p + 1;` now `p` point to `a[2]` (`3`). It is not necessary to multiply by `sizeof(int)`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY how would that be implemented in the code?Also read the edut in the question

Comment: I think that it is clear how to correct this mistake. Let's do it yourself.  Also There are  many examples on this site about the implementation of merge sort.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY which mistake?and i could not find any that used pointers.....I am talking about the error that the value is not being copied

Comment: I talk about _multiply by sizeof(int)_

Comment: @BLUEPIXY  okay but m approach should not be wrong either should it?and if so why?

Comment: I already showed examples about it. If you used `1*sizeof(int)` instead of `+1` it is obviously a mistake.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY not as to why my approach is wrong

Comment: First, Stop using `sizeof(int)` for index calculation.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I appreciate that you are trying to help but please also state the reasons as to why ?I use it because for eg; a[0] is located at 123, then a[1] should be located after an interval of the size of an int like this if size of an int is 4 then a[1] should be at 123+1*4 i.e 127 and a[2] at 123+2*4 i.e 131

Comment: If the size of `int` is 4 bytes it is obviously different to add 4 instead of 1.

Comment: See [DEMO](http://ideone.com/XvZTqS) The pointer knows the size of the pointing object, and its size is taken into account in pointer arithmetic, so it is not necessary to explicitly multiply the size.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thank you that does solve the not assigning error however it still is not giving the correct output

Comment: That is a mistake in your correction.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY The one I just updated now?

Comment: `debug  pritnf("%d\n",(*(b+(i ))));` can't compile this. Also `int *b=malloc(n );` --> `int *b=malloc(n * sizeof(int));` or `int *b=malloc(n*sizeof(*b) );`

Comment: `( *(a+(l1 )))=(*(b+(i )));` is wrong.

Comment: Okay.. but why?

Comment: What are you asking about?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Why is ( *(a+(l1 )))=(*(b+(i ))); this wrong?

Comment: `l1`  does not change in this loop. And what is that index?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thank you you have been most helpful it now works and that was a stupid mistake

Comment: @BLUEPIXY any idea....it works with a predefined array no matter what

Comment: Nevermind there was something wrong in the code wrote it again works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just looking at the code, the copy back loop needs to be fixed:

```
    for(i=low;i<=high;i++){
       ( *(a+(i )))=(*(b+(i )));   /* a+(i) not a+(l1) */
    }
```

The code isn't really pointer based, it's just using the alternate syntax for a[i] which is *(a+i). For a pointer based version of merge sort, low, mid, high should be pointers, not indices.

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: @7h3wh173r48817 - as mentioned in my answer, using pointers for low, mid, high would be more "pointer" oriented.

Comment: @7h3wh173r48817 - A more optimized merge sort does a one time allocation of a working array in an entry/helper function that calls the merge sort function, but this is simpler to implement using indices and not pointers. The copy back can be avoided by changing the direction of the merge (orginal->working or working->original), based of level of recursion either using two functions for the mergesort split part (each one calls the other) or a flag to keep track of even / odd recursion depth.

Comment: @7h3wh173r48817 - A [bottom up merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation) would be a bit faster.  I'm not sure if these optimizations are worth the effort for a class room program.